# Is there any reason to use UICollectionView for a grid view that's completely static?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm making a view with a 9 x 9 grid whose cells and layout will never change or scroll. I was thinking of using UICollectionView for this but the more I look into it the more I'm finding that it's geared towards grid views that scroll and may change and reposition. Is this a good assessment? If so, am I better off sticking with my own hand-rolled grid-based view? That would at least enable me to support devices running iOS versions < 6.

Comment: Poor assessment. Reevaluate, and focus on the UIColledtionViewFlowLayout class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer UICollectionView for grid based structure even its non scrollable. We should try to use native components and then we should customise them on need base.

1. Its manageable in future if you start supporting scrolling in future.
2. You can add functionality like cell deletion, cell addition with more precise APIs provided by Apple.
3. Views will be reusable.

And suppose you want support iOS < 6.0 , you can use "PSTCollectionView" which is open source library. This library checks iOS version and behaves accordingly.

```
  https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView
```

Answer (score 2):

If the cells do not need to scroll or change, then simply having a view with 9 subviews would be perfectly acceptable. Collection views are great for when the layout changes, such as on device rotation. If you support multiple orientations, this can still be handled without a collection view.

Answer (score 0):

If by static, you mean stationary, yes; and, not only for the reasons provided by the first answer. Here are some additional reasons, which I think are even stronger:

1. UICollectionView grid layouts accommodate orientation changes well;
2. UICollectionViewCell allows for better control over cell sizing based on other factors in addition to content size
3. UICollectionViewDatasourceDelegate simplifies connecting dynamic data to your view, and displaying updates to it

That's just three out of dozens of more reasons; for the rest of them, simply list every advantage the collection view framework provides.

The value of a collection view isn't based on scrolling at all; I say that because scrolling is not a part of the collection view framework. The collection view framework is a UIScrollViewDelegate. It is the UIScrollView class that provides scrolling.

Accordingly, all advantages that collection view provides are yours whether you choose to add scrolling or not.